# IndetityServer3 - redirect to consent page in infinite loop

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, identityserver3

It's the Identity Server 3 Standalone Implementation Part 3 by scott Brady

When I run my hybridflow client application and login ,the consent page shows.
But after I confirm my choices about the scope and click "yes,allow" button,the page redirect to consent page.

It's the network preserve log image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLU4h.png)

It's the final Http RequestURL and Its Response is the consent page.

https://localhost:44302/core/connect/authorize?client_id=hybridclient&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44304&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token+token&scope=openid+profile+email+roles+offline_access&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3dGIPazkL_z51B5u_wmtKMsauUJ34gMgYgAYukTOJgcMWmtASfBx-77WQfQAeTcMuAonf8NHohQTkf6gTmZIWKqBPnw3vjEf27KXPcD-q6xoDssEPwjcq_DtRck3TysSUmvF3PmqRzV2Prcukj8OJdRTOGBRUFBwXbf2_-low93P9joO_WqzC-a6M_nTG1JVy9AWUEaVPvPt1NdNU5Wwgq6A&nonce=636184232732125913.OGEyYzY4ODItYThjNi00ZDI1LWIxNDMtMTc2ZjUyNTNlYWM1MzI1ZjY2YjktMjg2MS00NDBkLTg4MDQtNDBkNzJjZWIyNTVm

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the returnUrl is always pointing at your singin page, which seems to always redirect to IdentityServer. Debug thru your code and you'll see where you re-enter your signin, even after the user has been logged in.